# Missing API key when making API RestMethod Call After HTTP Basic authentication in Mailchimp

Tags: powershell, mailchimp

In PowerShell, I was able to log in using HTTP Basic authentication For Mail Chimp.

```
$acctname = 'thisismyusername'
$password = 'thisismyapikey' 
$params = @{
    Uri = 'https://us14.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/';
    Method = 'Get'; #(or POST, or whatever)
    Headers = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("$($acctname):$($password)"));} #end headers hash table
} #end $params hash table

$var = Invoke-RestMethod @params
$var
```

When I try to get basic info on list thats id is "d3a7a4432d".

```
$URL = "https://us14.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/"
$Endpoint = "/lists/d3a7a4432d"
$URLMailChimp = "$URL$Endpoint"
$gist = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $URLMailChimp
```

I get this error message:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {
    "type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/",
    "title":"API Key Missing",
    "status":401,
    "detail":"Your request did not include an API key.",
    "instance":""
}
At line:7 char:9
+ $gist = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $URLMailChimp
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

I don't understand how to pass it my API key again. I thought by logging it it solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use MailChimp, but unless the first invocation provides you with an access token (and the [documentation](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/) as well as your error message don't look like it would) you need to provide the authentication header with every request.

```
$acctname = 'thisismyusername'
$password = 'thisismyapikey'
$URL      = 'https://us14.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/'
$listID   = 'd3a7a4432d'

$auth = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("${acctname}:${password}"))}

$gist = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri "$URL/lists/$listID" -Headers $auth
```

Comment: passing through a json object 

$JSON = ConvertTo-Json @{
          apikey = "thiskey" 
        }
$gist = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $URLMailChimp  -body $JSON